# jQuery stop entire function and fire another

Tags: jquery, function, loops

First function is running in a loop

```
function first()
{
    alert("first");
}

function defaultAnimation()
{
    (function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        first();
 }, 5000);

setTimeout(arguments.callee,5000);
})();
```

Second function is the same but with a slight change

```
function second()
{
    alert("second");
}

function defaultAnimation()
{
    (function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        second();
 },500);

setTimeout(arguments.callee,500);
})();
```

What I want is that when I click a div

```
$("#div").click(function(){});
```

Then the first function stops completely and the second one replaces it and starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use something like this (the key here is `clearTimeout` ):

```
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```

Comment: No my friend, it's not stopping the animation.

Comment: Hmmm interesting... it's working on jsfiddle but not on my code... let me investigate